# Python xlsxwriter microsoft visual studio code importing problem

Tags: python, python-import, xlsx, xlsxwriter

```
import xlsxwriter
```

> I do this in microsoft visual studio code and in cmd and it works just for the cmd why?
>
> It gives the error --> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
>
> I have checked the files and i searched the whole internet and i can't find any solution   -__-        appreciate your help.
>
> the weird part is that for example pyopenxl doesnt work aswell and i've been using studio code for programming python for more than a year and i never got importing errors like that

Comment: Make sure that you have selected your right virtual environment. Check these links for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/selecting-a-python-environment-for-a-project?view=vs-2019

Comment: The thing is that I never changed the environment I used since I have installed Microsoft visual studio code Wich is weird. I think u understand it wrong, I'm using visual studio code not the visual studio.

Comment: In the title and in the first line of your post you clearly state that you are using Visual Studio. Please edit your post.

Comment: That was my bad I edited it

Comment: No worries. About your issue this still sounds like a problem with your environments.

Comment: So how do u i access the environments

Comment: I searched for environments in visual studio code settings and found that im not using any environment so it should work as the cmd wich is weird -_-

Comment: I found out the error, it was using some statements that weren't necessary and were breaking it up, so i removed them and it works good now xD, but i did it manually so idk how to make it always like that because it has to do with the python runner, it runs for example in my case : C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/python/coronavirusdatascraping/scraper2.py

Comment: and if i run that in my console it doesnt work aswell so i removed the first statement and did : c:/Users/Asus/PycharmProjects/python/coronavirusdatascraping/scraper2.py and it worked so it's cool

Comment: I am glad that you sorted it out

Comment: I got it, so i had a bad instalation location and a good one aswell that's what it looks like so i could fix it by changing the python interpreter for the right one, thanks a lot for the help btw. appreciate it.